# Next.js 14 Dynamic layout with static content

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making eshop in next.js 14. I would like to make a navbar that is dynamic and on refresh is updated. But I also want to make my product details pages static, because they doesnt change so often. But here comes a problem. When I reload page on this static product detail page, navbar doesnt include cart items and user sign in status. In documentation is: `Force static rendering and cache the data of a layout or page by forcing cookies(), headers() and useSearchParams() to return empty values.`. Is it possible to render navbar on every request and inject static content to it?

I tried mixing dynamic config option in page and in layout `export const dynamic = 'force-static'` but without any good results.

Comment: Are you using the new Next.js router system? If so, are you rendering your navbar in your main `layout` file? Are you using `use client` in your navbar?

Comment: Yes I am using new app router, navbar is server component and the cart button is client component that Is in navbar.

Comment: Can you post your code for your navbar? or create a codesandbox so we can see and demo your code?

Comment: https://github.com/mrWintex/nextjs-header

Comment: I am using cookies to get the cart data from the server, so I think on the static pages I will fetch cart on the client. That should work, but it wont eliminate initial loading states...